# how to notify a UIViewController that a button was clicked in a xib file using a delegate in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, delegates, xib

I'm a bit stuck.
I have a `UIViewController` and a custom `pop.xib` that extends `UIView`. 
`pop.xib` is connected to `pop.swift`.
In the `UIViewController` a button makes the `.xib` file pop up.

And in `pop.xib` there is a button that is clicked to send some data to the database.

But when that button is clicked in `pop.xib` to send data I want the `UIViewController` to

a) know when the `@IBAction func sendDataToDbAction(_ sender: Any)` is clicked and

b) when the if statement returns false from inside `sendDataToDbAction` then present an alert on the `UIViewController`

```
//pop.swift

     class Pop: UIView {

            @IBOutlet var delegate: AnswerDelegate?

            @IBAction func sendDataToDbAction(_ sender: Any)
            {
                     if(answer == false)
                     {
                          don't send to db
                          alert pops up saying answer is false
                     }
                     else
                     {

                     }

            }
         }
```

I've set up a delegate in pop.swift

```
//pop.swift

@objc protocol AnswerDelegate {

    func isCorrectAnswer()
}



//UIViewController

extension UIViewController:AnswerDelegate{

//set the pop.xib delegate to self
// implement func isCorrectAnswer

}
```

I'm just not sure how I can use the delegate to do what I want.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this out, you can do it like this.

Pop.swift

```
@objc protocol AnswerDelegate {
    func isCorrectAnswer()
}

class Pop: UIView {

    var answerDelegate: AnswerDelegate?

    class func instanceFromNib() -> Pop {
        return UINib(nibName: "Pop", bundle: nil).instantiate(withOwner: nil, options: nil)[0] as! Pop
    }

    @IBAction func sendDataToDbAction(_ sender: Any)
    {
        if(answer == false) {
            //Alert
        }
        else {
            answerDelegate?.isCorrectAnswer()
        }
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, AnswerDelegate {

    func isCorrectAnswer() {

    }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        let popView = Pop.instanceFromNib()
        popView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 50)
        popView.answerDelegate = self

        self.view.addSubview(popView)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not so sure you can do this on an extension, as you need to set the delegate somewhere in your view controller.

Adjust your pop.swift to call the delegate function as below:

```
@IBAction func sendDataToDbAction(_ sender: Any) {
  if(answer == false) {
    // show alert
  } else {
    delegate?.isCorrectAnswer()
  }
}
```

In your view controller, set the delegate and add the function as below:

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController, AnswerDelegate {

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    pop.delegate = self
  }

  func isCorrectAnswer() {
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to create two classes one is UIViewController and one is for XIB as follows. And add a protocol and its delegate function. override delegate method in your viewController to achieve your result.

**LoginVC.swift**

```
import UIKit

class LoginVC: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate, RegisterViewDelegate {

    func shiftRegisterViewUpDelegateFunction() {
        if isRegister {
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.1, delay: 0, options: .curveEaseIn, animations: {
                self.registerView.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: 0)
                self.loginView.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: 0)
            })
            isRegister = false
        } else {
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.1, delay: 0, options: .curveEaseIn, animations: {
                var yaxis = CGFloat()
                if GlobalConstants.kIphone_5 {
                    yaxis = -(1.0*self.loginView.frame.size.height)+150
                } else {
                    yaxis =  -(1.0*self.loginView.frame.size.height)+170
                }
                self.registerView.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: yaxis)
                self.loginView.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: yaxis)
            })
            isRegister = true
        }
    }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        //Adding subviews
        self.addSubviewsOverMainView()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(true)
    }

    func addSubviewsOverMainView() {


        registerView = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("RegisterView", owner: self, options: nil)?[0] as! RegisterView
        if GlobalConstants.kIphone_5 {
            registerView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: self.view.frame.size.height-150, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: self.view.frame.size.height)
        }else {
            registerView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: self.view.frame.size.height-150, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: self.view.frame.size.height)
        }
        registerView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleHeight, .flexibleWidth]
        self.view.addSubview(registerView)
        registerView.delegate = self
    }

}
```

**RegisterXIB.swift**

```
import UIKit

protocol RegisterViewDelegate {
    func shiftRegisterViewUpDelegateFunction()
}

class RegisterView: UIView, UIScrollViewDelegate {

    var delegate: RegisterViewDelegate?
    var isRotated = Bool()
    @IBOutlet weak var containerView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var formView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var shiftUpBtn: UIButton!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        let scrollview = UIScrollView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.containerView.frame.size.width, height: self.containerView.frame.size.height))
        scrollview.delegate = self
        scrollview.contentSize = CGSize(width: self.containerView.frame.size.width, height: 500)
        scrollview.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = true
        scrollview.isScrollEnabled = true
        scrollview.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        scrollview.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        scrollview.addSubview(formView)
        containerView.addSubview(scrollview)
    }

    @IBAction func shiftRegistrationUpAction(_ sender: Any) {
        if isRotated {
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.2) {
                self.isRotated = false
                self.shiftUpBtn.transform = .identity
            }
        } else {
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.2) {
                self.isRotated = true
                self.shiftUpBtn.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: .pi)
            }
        }
        self.delegate?.shiftRegisterViewUpDelegateFunction()
    }
}
```